# Fastest way to load bitmap, re-using bitmap once created

Tags: android, bitmap, java-native-interface

I have an application where I am generating many Bitmap objects.  Once I create a bitmap, all the remaining bitmaps will be the same size.

Currently I can I load/create a new bitmap in about 50-80 ms on my phone, which works for what I need.  However due to the rapid pace of creating these I am hitting constant GC.

I would like to re-use the same bitmap object, but am not sure how to do this through the sdk.

I did compile libjpeg and load my images through the NDK and re-use my bitmaps, however my loading speed  dropped to about 200 ms, which is too slow.
I'll post code later when I have it in front of me.

Questions:

Is there a way to re-use my bitmap objects to avoid GC?
Is there a faster way to load my images through the NDK?  Is it possible to hook in to the way the OS is loading the bitmaps?  I know about libjpegTurbo, but I cannot get it to compile currently(another topic for another day).

Any other thoughts on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a hashmap to store your bitmaps? Then when you load a bitmap, check to see if its in the hashmap first and if it is you can reuse it. If it is not in the hashmap, save it normally and then insert it into the hashmap.

Comment: I am creating about 20 bitmaps a sec, so I can't keep them all in memory.  I actually have a background thread populating a queue that I'm pulling new bitmaps from.  The big issue is in my background thread instead of creating new bitmap objects, I would like to pull from a pool of bitmaps and just re-use them so I don't have to have as  much GC.

Comment: @broschb If you can't keep them in memory, then how can you re-use them? You realize that doesn't make sense right? If you have memory limitations your best bet is to then is to implement an image cache using a hashmap and queue, and then once you reach a certain limit on the number of bitmaps loaded to remove older bitmaps from the queue and hint to the GC that they should be cleared out of memory. The hashmap will be used to identify if the bitmap is currently in the queue and its location.

Comment: I can re-use the bitmap by changing the pixel data of the bitmap, with the new pixel data from another bitmap.  See @Samuels response, I think this is along the track I am thinking.

Comment: @broschb Every pixel in the Bitmap or int array takes up 4 bytes of memory. That means a 700x400 int array takes up ~273 kilobytes already. I highly doubt a Bitmap object takes up more than one kilobyte of memory, a couple kilobytes max. If you can hold all the int arrays in memory, you will almost certainly be able to hold all the Bitmap objects. The int array is the vast majority of the Bitmap object, so if you are not implementing any caching I doubt it will solve your GC problems.

Comment: @onit The 700x400 bitmap should take up about 1.1MB.

Comment: @Samuel If you are right then I am surprised by how inefficient the Bitmap object is. In either case, he should still cache the image data.

Comment: So I tried many different approaches, and as one would resolve one issue I would encounter another.  In the end I ended up loading my bitmap using Bitmapfactory.decode file as this was the fastest approach I could find, and was very careful about controlling the loading/destroying the resources on my background threads.  Doing this I was able to tune everything to give the desired results.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using IntBuffer(s) which contain the pixel data that you need to swap out. Then, create one bitmap of the size you need, and when you need to swap out the pixels, use bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(). I imagine it will be MUCH faster than allocating/deallocating bitmap memory every time you need to change the pixel data. It might be a good idea to keep the buffers in a hashmap if you want to keep them in memory for quick retrieval.

Optionally you could use setPixels() with an array of int's. The nice thing about copyPixelsFromBuffer() is that no pixel conversion is attempted, and there are less options, so it might be a little faster.

Comment: I like the idea of an int buffer, but the only significant gain here I see is possibly memory space. The fastest way will be to keep the objects in memory, in which case this will only be a significant improvement if the int buffers are significantly smaller than the bitmap object. I have my doubts about that, unless the bitmaps are relatively small.

Comment: Where is the pixel data coming from? It must be an int array at some point, right? So if you're allocating a bitmap each time then you have memory for the int array and memory for the bitmap. Assuming you are done with the int array, that's one object that needs to be garbage collected. Then when you are done with the bitmap, it will also need to be garbage collected. That's two big objects that need to be garbage collected. If you use only one bitmap, you won't have the extra object that needs to be garbage collected. Bitmap GC takes longer because it also has JNI calls.

Comment: If you are reusing the bitmaps in memory, GC no longer becomes a big issue, unless you have an enormous amount of images you cannot cache in memory (I've personally stored hundreds of bitmaps fine in memory on newer phones). I imagine that at least 95% of the memory used by a Bitmap is the actual underlying int array as well, unless you have very small bitmaps. If he can just cache the Bitmaps in memory (which will be the biggest performance gain), I doubt this will be a significant performance gain. If he needs to constantly recycle the Bitmaps, I agree that it will be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, I'll look into some of these.  The images I am dealing with are about 700x400, I can get about 8-10 in memory before I start to hit issues.  I had a previous implementation that was re-using(replacing pixel data) on bitmaps, that greatly reduced GC, but I ran into other implementations in my app with my prev. approach, and had to move to loading the images.

Comment: @Samuel and onit, thanks for the help and suggestions.  Looking at this, want to run some tests with the IntBuffers approach.  How would I load an image directly into IntBuffers?  The only way I can see to do this would be to load the bitmap, get the pixels and load into an intBuffer, but i'm sure i'm missing an obvious way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "load the bitmap"? Once you get an int array, you can just wrap it in an IntBuffer (it's very quick, nothing is copied) by calling IntBuffer.wrap(intArray).

Comment: @Samuel, I am confused on how to actually get the int array from the image on disk.  I can get an intArray by calling Bitmap.getPixels, but this still requires creation of a bitmap object.  Is there a way to just directly load the pixels directly into an int array?  Or the other option I can see is to load the bytes and create a byteBuffer, and then create an intBuffer from that.  Are those the approaches or am I missing something?